# Create std::list with std::multimap iterators

Tags: c++, list, optimization, std, multimap

I have the following function:

```
std::list<std::shared_ptr<Object>> AnimalManager::GetObjectsOfType(std::string type)
{    
    std::pair <std::multimap<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Object>>::iterator, std::multimap<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Object>>::iterator> ret;
    ret = m_objects.equal_range(type);

    std::list<std::shared_ptr<Object>> objectsOfType(ret.first, ret.second);

    return objectsOfType;
}
```

I'm creating a list with a range of iterators but I'm getting an error. I due to the iterators in the multimap are pairs and elements in list are uniques. But I don't want to iterate thought iterators because I'll lose the benefit I get using `std::multimap` instead other data strcuture with O(1) insertion but O(n) find.

**Is possible to create a list as I want to do it? Or would it be better If I use another design pattern or data structure?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need it [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to *transform* the range into a different one.  Making use of a lambda you could construct the list like

```
std::list<std::shared_ptr<Object>> AnimalManager::GetObjectsOfType(std::string type)
{    
    auto ret = m_objects.equal_range(type);

    std::list<std::shared_ptr<Object>> objectsOfType;
    std::transform((ret.first, ret.second, std::back_inserter(objectsOfType),
                   [](const auto& pair){ return pair.second; });

    return objectsOfType;
}
```